# Java SQLite JDBC "SELECT" statement very slow

Tags: java, performance, sqlite, select, jdbc

From an API i get ~9000 entries which i have to insert into a table. Detailed data for every of these entries is stored in another table with ~45000 entries

Now i am trying to insert these 9000 entries into a new table and getting the needed information about these entries from the other table.

The SELECT statement for the data in the table with 45000 entries takes something between 30-90ms each time.

The code for the select is as follows (Repeated 9000 times):

```
                long startTime = System.nanoTime();

                PreparedStatement selectDB = cStatic.prepareStatement("SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM DB WHERE ID = ?");
                selectDB.setInt(1, rsIDs.getInt(3));

                ResultSet rsDB = selectDB.executeQuery();

                long endTime = System.nanoTime();

                long duration = (startTime - endTime) / 1000000;
```

From the whole process (collecting information, iserting) the SELECT + ResultSet alone take 95% of the processing time, i'd like to know how i can speed this up

Since i already searched for solutions i am already using indexes for "getInt/getString" from result set and also only call the needed columns of the table instead of the full row, but only a very minor improvement.

Every other statement (UPDATE , INSERT, DELETE) hardly even uses 1ms, why is SELECT needing so much time?

EDIT:

Didn't really speed up the SELECT , but i was rebuilding the code to only use the SELECT once and store every important data into an array , now it's done in 2-3 seconds instead of 5 minutes.

Thanks to Rahul i tried giving the columns an index and it helped a bit too:

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX `idx_id` (`ID`);

Comment: Is ~30 millisec that slow for you? Select needs to return a resultset, other queries don't...

Comment: Well, in my process i am building a second table with ~9000 entries, these need data from the first table.

9000 * 30ms is roughly 4,5 minutes, which is indeed quite a lot for me, considering inserting 200.000 entries happens in some seconds...

Comment: So your actual problem is the slowness in building the other table? You should edit the question to reflect this. Doing things _row-by-row_ will always be slow. Instead of running multiple `SELECT`s you should do everything (`SELECT` & `INSERT`) in one single statement.

Comment: I changed it now to only use one select for everything and yeah, it's working nice, thanks

Answer (score 0):

30ms shouldn't be counted as slow though, you may want to make sure that you have a index created or index in place for the `ID` column since you are using that column in your `WHERE` condition as `WHERE ID = ?`

No I mean create an unique index on `ID` column if you don't have already by saying below which will eventually speed up your query by performing an index scan.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX `idx_id` (`ID`);
```

Comment: do you mean instead of "WHERE ID = ?" i would write "WHERE columnIndexOfID = ?"

Comment: It's a little bit faster with this change, nothing too big but with the other change (using only one select) it's really fast , thank you